# Pho remove all occurrences of an exact word with changing digits

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a variable sting in the format of below
?abc=1&abc=14&others=something

String abc may present or not.
I want to remove all occurrences of “abc=Anynumber&” if this presents in the string.

Tried preg_replace(\abc/d+/&, “, $string) but not working.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
$input = "?abc=1&abc=14&others=something";
$output = preg_replace("/(?<=\?|&)abc=\d+&?/", "", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
?abc=1&abc=14&others=something
?others=something
```

Comment: You could also use a character class instead of the `|` in the lookbehind `(?<=[?&])abc=\d+&?` +1

Comment: @Thefourthbird You're right, it helps to not be on a cell phone when answering :-)